# Using Jquery how do i validate Select box in this situation?

Tags: php, jquery, mysql

This is the code ,not the entire code but a small part of it.
I need a code snippet for  validate the Select box.Other field's validations are working fine.
Really appreciate your help..

```
    <label>Locality :</label><select name="locality" class="locality">
    <option value="default" id="select" class="required">--Select locality--</option>';
    //<option selected="selected"></option>

    $query2 = "Select * from locality_master";  
    $res = mysqli_query($conn, $query2) or die("Error in Selecting select box locality master " . mysqli_error($conn));
    while($r=mysqli_fetch_array($res)){

        echo "<option value='" . $r['l_id'] ."'>" . $r['l_name'] ."</option>";
    }
    echo "</select>";

    print '
    <label>Street :</label> <select name="street" class="street" >
    <option selected="selected">--Select Street--</option>
    </select>
    <img id="loding1"></img>
    <br><br>
```

Existing Jquery validation

```
$(function() {

// Setup form validation on the #register-form element
$("#register-form").validate({

    // Specify the validation rules
    rules: {
        name: "required",
        address: "required",
        state: "required",
        city: "required",
        postalcode: "required",

    // Specify the validation error messages
    messages: {
        name: "Please enter your first name",
        address: "Please enter your address:",
        state: "Please provide a state:",
        city: "Please provide a city:",
        postalcode: "Please Provide us with a postal code"

    },

    submitHandler: function(form) {
        form.submit();
    }
    }
  });

 });
```

What should I add to Jquery to validate select box ??

Comment: What kind of validation you need? required?

Comment: Jquery validation...a code snippet to add in the existing jquery

Comment: ok. so you can add the validation in the same way you are doing for other inputs

Comment: Also you can do  <select name="locality" class="locality" required> in the HTML itself

Comment: @aju john Not working,

Comment: add locality on rules required and also on message both . and leave a 

<select name="locality" class="locality" value=""> value blank

Comment: @amit chauhan Not working

Comment: i posted the answer plz refer it @PrathameshSarang

Comment: you did not complete the rules brace and i also modified your code try it will helps you sure

Comment: How can you comment html using //   ???                                                       '//<option selected="selected"></option>'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

leave blank value in option of your select locality

```
  <option value="" id="select" class="required">--Select locality--</option>
```

and put rules and message

```
// Setup form validation on the #register-form element
$("#register-form").validate({

    // Specify the validation rules
    rules: {
        name: "required",
        address: "required",
        state: "required",
        city: "required",
        postalcode: "required",
        locality  : "required"
     },

    // Specify the validation error messages
    messages: {
        name: "Please enter your first name",
        address: "Please enter your address:",
        state: "Please provide a state:",
        city: "Please provide a city:",
        postalcode: "Please Provide us with a postal code",
        locality  : "Please Select Locality."

    },

    submitHandler: function(form) 
    {
        form.submit();
    }

});
```

Answer (score 0):

Do this within submit Handler

`if($('.locality option:selected').text() == '--Select locality--'){
   return false;
   // and alert message
}`

Comment: alert("please select any option for locality");

Answer (score 0):

Add value attribute to your option tag like this:

```
<option value="" selected="selected">--Select Street--</option>
```

And then add the select box to your validation like this:

```
// Specify the validation rules
    rules: {
        name: "required",
        address: "required",
        state: "required",
        city: "required",
        postalcode: "required",
        street: "required"

    // Specify the validation error messages
    messages: {
        name: "Please enter your first name",
        address: "Please enter your address:",
        state: "Please provide a state:",
        city: "Please provide a city:",
        postalcode: "Please Provide us with a postal code",
        street: "Please provide a street"    
    },
```